# How to display 3 input box with text & submit button in a row

Tags: html, css

In this code the 1st box is not coming in a row else other 2 are having no problem.

Following is the code:

```
<div class="foo">
  <div class="bar">1<input id="J" type="textt" style="width:40% height:20%" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="textboxx"/>
</div>
  <div class="bar"><input type="submit"></div>
</div>
</br>

  <div class="bar">2<input id="J" type="textt" style="width:40% height:20%" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="textboxx"/>
</div>
  <div class="bar"><input type="submit"></div>
</div>

</br>
  <div class="bar">3<input id="J" type="textt" style="width:40% height:20%" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="textboxx"/>
</div>
  <div class="bar"><input type="submit"></div>
</div>
```

& the CSS

```
.foo {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.bar {
  display: table-cell;
}

.bar:first-child, input[type="text"] {
  width: 20%;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: If you want to have table layout and data is table indeed, do not hesitate using tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/saUK7/)

CSS:

```
.foo {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.row
{
    display:block;
}

.bar {
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="foo">
      <div class = "row">
      <div class="bar"> 1
          <input id="J" type="text" style="width:40% height:20%" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="textboxx"/>
      </div>
      <div class="bar"><input type="submit"/></div>
     </div>

    <div class = "row">
      <div class="bar"> 2
          <input id="J" type="text" style="width:40% height:20%" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="textboxx"/>
      </div>
      <div class="bar"><input type="submit"/></div>
     </div>

      <div class = "row">
      <div class="bar"> 3
          <input id="J" type="text" style="width:40% height:20%" autocomplete="off" autofocus class="textboxx"/>
      </div>
      <div class="bar"><input type="submit"/></div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

use table  instead of div. give every input in a

```
    <td> <input type ="text"\> <\td>
```

tag

Answer (score 0):

just change the `width` from `20px` to  `29.5%`

```
  .bar:first-child, input[type="text"] {
    width: 29.5%;
    }
```

DEMO:http://jsfiddle.net/LrshX/

Answer (score 0):

Change foo class from `display:table` to `display:inline`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are overcomplicating things for no reason. And you have messed up (somewhat) your HTML tags, your CSS styles etc.
What (I believe) you are after, could be achieved (among many ways) like this:

HTML

```
<div class="foo">
    <div class="bar">
        1
        <input type="text" id="J1" class="textbox"
               autocomplete="off" autofocus />
    </div>
    <div class="bar"><input type="submit" /></div>
</div>
<br />
...
```

CSS

```
.foo {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

.bar { display: table-cell; }

.bar:first-child { width: 20%; }

input[type="text"] { width: 80%; }
```

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/M9dYc/)**.

---

***Some additional remarks:***

1. Do not use the same `id` on multiple elements in your DOM, or you're very likely to experience unexpected behaviour.
2. If you use `autofocus` on all text-fields, the ladt one will receive the focus.
3. If you want your `submit` buttons to actually do something, don't forget to include them in `form` or bind them using JavaScript.